# What's the difference between "anesthesia" and "anesthetic"?

Tags: american-english

What's the difference between the words "anesthesia" and "anesthetic"?

Comment: What does the dictionary tell you?  Can you add that information to your question please, along with the aspects of it which you still don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Anesthesia** refers to the state of being insensitive to pain.  *"He was given anesthesia."*

**Anesthetic** refers to the substance or other method by which the state is induced.  *"He was given an anesthetic."*

Comment: I don't think *He was given anesthesia* is a very natural usage - it would be like saying *He was given numbness*. A more obvious *(syntactic)* distinction would be that unlike ***anesthesia***, ***anesthetic*** can also be used adjectivally.

Comment: How would you consider "he was put under anesthesia"?  That seems to be very common, but using the definition of anesthesia as a state ("he was put under numbness"), it doesn't work either.

Comment: My apologies. I've just made a "non-edit" to your text so I could cancel my downvote. Looking at [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=under+anaesthesia%2Cunder+anaesthetic&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunder%20anaesthesia%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunder%20anaesthetic%3B%2Cc0) it seems that even with the BrE corpus and spelling, ***under anaesthesia*** is still more common ***under anaesthetic*** (though it does rather look as thought the *trend* is towards the version I'm more familiar with).